# VS Code: Find occurrences of text only in changes made by me

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-blame

When I use `ctrl+shift+f` I want to find only those text occurrences, which git registered as made by me.

[image]

Comment: write a task that asks what to find (`${input}`) executes a `git blame` and `grep`s the output on your username and find text and set a `problemmatcher` to create clickable PROBLEMS

Comment: How to write such a task?

Comment: write a script that uses an argument (what to search), call this script by a task with an `${input}` variable that is the script argument, add a `problemmatcher` to the task to find the filename and line/char position

Comment: It should be cmd executable? I never wrote one, I can do it in notepad right? Or I need another tool?

Comment: that script can be Python, NodeJS, .....

Comment: if you have git, you have Git Bash terminal, can you use it as the task terminal and just write a bash script with the 2 commands `git blame | grep $*`, call this script in the task

Comment: thank you for explaining, I will try to create it and report my finding here